# How to get the last date of previous three months

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello i would like to know how to get the last date of previous three months in Oracle.i tried using the following query to get the result but it showed me the first date of the months.

Query :

```
select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(last_day(SYSDATE),-level),'MONTH'),'DD-MM-YYYY') month 
from dual
connect by level<4;
```

Output i am desiring to get :

```
30-NOV-2015
31-OCT-2015
30-SEP-2015
```

Thanks.

Comment: when did i ever mention about downloading anything in the first place?i got my answer already.

Comment: What's the reason for down-voting? (Sorry was the auto-correction)

Comment: oh yes that i was wondering too when i saw the down-vote in my question earlier.if you or anybody else can up-vote or make it 0 atleast,i would appreciate it as i cant find any valid reason for the down-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `LAST_DAY()`

```
select TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(last_day(SYSDATE),-level)),'DD-MM-YYYY') month 
from dual
connect by level<4;
```

Comment: its showing me the following error when i try to execute it.

ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Comment: @Iftekhar just mismatched brackets.. Corrected.